# Prove: Cartesian product of power sets of A is equinumerous to power set of A

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If A has at least two elements and A x A ~ A then P(A) x P(A) ~ P(A). Hint: If A und B disjoint, then P(A U B) ~ P(A) x P(B). Is the following reasoning correct? Since A has at least two elements and A x A ~ A, it can not be finite. Thus A infinite. Let X be an infinite subset of A. Then (A-X) ~ A and X ~ A and P((A-X) U X) = P(A) ~ P(A-X) x P(X) ~ P(A) x P(A). However, this assumes A being denumerable? Is there another way (using the hint) without assuming denumerability?

Comment: What makes you think that $P(A-X)\times P(X) \sim P(A)$? Not every subset of $A$ is either a subset of $X$ or a subset of $A-X$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: X and A-X are infinite, thus equinumerous to A. A-X and X are disjoint, so P(AUB)~P(A)xP(B) applies.

Comment: What makes you think that both being infinite make them equinumerous? $\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N}$ are not both equinumerous to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: Is it not true that every infinite set can be put into a 1-1 correspondence with a proper subset of itself? Example: Natural numbers with subsets even and odd numbers? As I mentioned I assumed denumerabilty. How can the proof be fixed without this assumption.

Comment: Yes, it is true, but that is not what you said. You said that $X$ was infinite and co-infinite, and **therefore** that it was equinumerous with $A$. There is a difference between "I can choose $X$ to have this property" and "I deduce that $X$ will necessarily have this property." You picked $X$ to be an **arbitrary** infinite subset of $A$, not a carefully chosen one. If you want to pick $X$ as having a particular property, you have to say you are picking $X$ with that property, rather than to pretend that you can conclude it has it ex nihilo.

Comment: In addition, even assuming your $X$ was chosen with the desired property, you are using what you want to prove: you are trying to prove that $P(A)\sim P(A)\times P(A)$; but you are **using** this to claim that because $A-X\sim A$ and $X\sim A$, then $P(A)\sim P(A-X)\times P(X)$. *That's what you are trying to prove*.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: I agree, X should be chosen with the desired property. Regarding your second thought: If X~A and A-X~A, then P(X)~P(A) and P(A-X)~P(A) and then P(A-X)x(P(X)~P(A)xP(A). I omitted these steps in the proof and it is not circular.

Comment: I have no problem with your claim that, if $X$ is properly chosen, then $P(A)\sim P(A-X)$ and $P(A)\sim P(X)$. But you are asserting that $P(A) \sim P(A-X)\times P(X)$, and that is exactly what you are trying to prove in the first place. You have no warrant for **that** equality.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: To clarify, If P(A)~P(A-X) and P(A)~P(X) then P(A)xP(A)~P(A-X)xP(X). But from (A-X)UX=A and P((A-X)UX)~P(A-X)xP(X) (by the lemma of the hint), P(A)~P(A)xP(A) follows.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: The HINT did not say that $P(A\cup B) \sim P(A)\times P(B)$. It said $P(A\cup B) \sim P(A)\cup P(B)$. That I believe when $A$ and $B$ are infinite; but now that you’ve changed it, the hint is not a hint, it’s assuming what you are trying to prove. So this is all circular nonsense unless you actually **prove** the hint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing this in a too roundabout way. You should not need to go through the conclusion that $A$ is infinite.

First, let’s prove the hint:

**Lemma.** If $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, then $P(A\cup B)\sim P(A)\times P(B)$.

*Proof.* Define $f\colon P(A)\times P(B)\to P(A\cup B)$ as follows: given $S\subseteq A$ and $T\subseteq B$, let $f(S,T)=S\cup T\subseteq A\cup B$.

First, $f$ is surjective: if $X\subseteq A\cup B$, then let $S=X\cap A$ and $T=X\cap B $. Then $X=S\cup T = f(S,T)$.

Second: $f$ is one-to-one: Suppose that $f(S,T) = f(X,Y)$. Then $S\cup T = X\cup Y$. Now, $X=X\cap(X\cup Y) =X\cap(S\cup T) = (X\cap S)\cup (X\cap T)$. Since $X\subseteq A$, $T\subseteq B$, and $A\cap B=\varnothing$, then $X\cap T\subseteq A\cap B = \varnothing$. Thus, $X=X\cap S$, proving that $X\subseteq S$. Symmetrically, $S\subseteq X$, hence $S=X$. The same argument, *mutatis mutandis* yields $T=Y$. Thus, $f$ is one-to-one.

We have therefore exhibited a bijection between $P(A\cup B)$ and $P(A)\times P(B)$, so $P(A\cup B)\sim P(A)\times P(B)$. $\Box$

Now, suppose $A$ is a set with at least two elements such that $A\sim A\times A$. Let $f\colon A\to A\times A$ be a bijection. We want to prove that $P(A)\sim P(A)\times P(A)$.

Let $a,b\in A$, $a\neq b$. Note that $A\sim A\times\{a\}$, $A\sim A\times\{b\}$, and that $A\times\{a\}$ is disjoint from $A\times\{b\}$. So we have
$$\begin{align*}
P(A)\times P(A) &\sim P(A\times\{a\})\times P(A\times\{b\})\\
&\sim P((A\times\{a\})\cup (A\times\{b\}))\\
&= P(A\times\{a,b\}).
\end{align*}$$
Now, $A\times\{a,b\}$ embeds into $A\times A$, so $P(A\times\{a,b\})$ embeds into $P(A\times A)$. And since $A\times A\sim A$, then $P(A\times\{a,b\})$ embeds into $P(A\times A)\sim P(A)$. Thus, $P(A)\times P(A)$ embeds into $P(A)$.

Conversely, $P(A)$ embeds into $P(A)\times P(A)$ (for example, by mapping $X$ to $(X,\varnothing)$).

Thus, $P(A)\preceq P(A)\times P(A)$ and $P(A)\times P(A)\preceq P(A)$. By Cantor-Bernstein’s Theorem, $P(A)\sim P(A)\times P(A)$, as desired. $\Box$

Note that we did not need to use any properties of infinite sets (which may be defined simply as “not finite” rather than as “bijectable with a proper subset”; and in any case, the proof that $A$ can be decomposed as a disjoint union of two equipollent sets, each bijectable with $A$, when $A$ is infinite is a theorem that would need to be proven; it does not follow directly from the definition). Also, I don’t *think* we use the Axiom of Choice in the argument above, another plus.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and time! That was the sort of proof I was looking for. In contrast, my proof rested on a few assumptions: 1) A is denumerable. 2) One can find a denumerable subset X such that A-X and X are equinumerous with A (which can be proven). 3) The theorem of the hint (however, it was given as already proven but unfortunately contained an error in my initial post).

Comment: @KCK: You never actually use that $A$ is denumerable; what you use is that $A$ is infinite (which you would really need to prove formally, and you didn't, from $A\sim A\times A$ and $A$ has at least two elements), and that if $A$ is infinite, then we can decompose $A$ into a disjoint union of two sets that are bijectable with $A$. Even the definition of infinite that says "bijectable with a proper subset" does not, by itself, yield a bijectable proper subset whose complement is *also* bijectable with the original set.

Answer (score 1):

If A is infinite then
$$|P(A)| = 2^{|A|} = 2^{|A|+|A|} = 2^{|A|} × 2^{|A|} = |P(A)|×|P(A)| = |P(A)×P(A)|$$